# pointcloud_to_laserscan with ldmrs data

Tags: ros, 2dlaserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying  to covert Pointcloud2 msgs obtained by a SICK LD-MRS four layer scanner to Laserscan msgs. i tried to use the pointcloud_to_laserscan package, but it did not work. Following is what i get:

```
$ roslaunch pointcloud_to_laserscan sample_node.launch

logging to /home/grapeson/.ros/log/c4b31a3c-b80d-11e7-b725-141877a62928/roslaunch-grapeson-Inspiron.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 746, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 718, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 682, in _recurse_load
    val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 587, in _include_tag
    inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 370, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 383, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 151, in _find
    source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 197, in _find_executable
    full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)

**ResourceNotFound: openni2_launch**

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

*It reports that "ResourceNotFound: openni2_launch", and then I tried *

```
$ rospack find openni2
```

*and i get *

```
[rospack] Error: package 'openni2' not found
```

*What can I do now? can anybody help? Thanks*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273921/pointcloud_to_laserscan-with-ldmrs-data/) by [grapeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/32370/grapeson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-24**:
Welcome! To make your question easier to read (and hopefully get more people reading it) I formatted your text. Please use the `101010` button to format your code and terminal input/output in the future.

**Comment by [grapeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/32370/grapeson/) on 2017-10-27**:
Thanks a lot！`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really a stupid question. we should adjust the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [grapeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/32370/grapeson/) with karma: 16 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-06**:
What do you mean? *How* should you adjust the launch file?